# Find the domain of $g(x) = \ln \left( {\frac{x}{{x - 1}}} \right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I know the argument of the function has to be greater than 0, so:

$\eqalign{
  & \left( {\frac{x}{{x - 1}}} \right) > 0  \cr 
  & x > 0 \cr} $

however in this case $x \ne 1$, $x \ne 0$ as they result in an answer which is undefined, so I think it's reasonable for me to say the domain is $x>1$, however this is not the correct answer.

Comment: This kind of questions is rather ill formulated. The domain of this function can be lots of things, the domain should be formulated _before_ giving the expression for the function. However, given the expression there is a _largest possible_ domain that could be specified without without needing any supplement to the expression, namely the set of all values$~x$ for which this expression has an unambiguous value; that maximal set is probably what they are asking for.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen , yeah: the tags are precalculus and logarithms, so this question most probably is high schoolish and they usually mean the maximal *possible* domain in the real realm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the actual intervals on which the function is defined, what we need is:

$$\Big(\underbrace{x-1 > 0 \;\text{ AND }  \;x > 0}_{\large \;\rightarrow x \;\gt \;1}\Big) \;\text{ or else }\; \Big(\underbrace{x - 1 <0 \;\text{AND}\;x< 0}_{\large \rightarrow \;x\;< \;0}\Big)$$

So the the function's domain is given by $$(-\infty, 0) \cup (1,\infty)$$

Comment: Nicely illustrated +1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: In order for $\dfrac{x}{x-1}$ to be positive, the numerator and denominator must have the same sign.